# How to write Nginx Config file to pass URL with id ([0-9]+) to perform Load Balancing

Tags: express, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

suppose I have to go to an URL `localhost/tag/9` where 9 is an id.So what do I need to write inside

```
location /tag/? {

}
```

The thing is actually I have several tags(links) in a webpage and each tag has an id associated with them.When I click on a tag having id 9,It takes me to `localhost/tag/9` and I get 404 error.Now I want to know how to proxy_pass this URL to my actual URL which is `localhost:1111/tag/9` ? My express app is running on port 1111 and 2222 and 3333.

My conf file so far

```
upstream expressweb {
    server localhost:1111;
    server localhost:2222;
    server localhost:3333;
}
server {

    listen 80;
    location /my_app/ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/;
    }
    location /tag/[0-9]+/ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/$1/;
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i do it?

Edit:

I have tried doing

```
location /tag/1/ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/1/;
    }
    location /tag/2/ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/2/;
    }
    location /tag/3/ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/3/;
    }
```

and so and its working fine.But I am still struggling to write it with regex.

**Solved it**

writing the regex part as such did the work for me.One thing to note here is that any regex must be wrapped up by () in nginx config file.And the `$` at the end indicates the regex values will be at the end of an URL

```
 location ~ /([1-9][0-9]*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/$1/;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx serves files, not tags in a webpage - that can mean multiple things to start with.

Provided that the page your nginx serves as you suggest references a file located at http://expressweb/tag/9 (and you can get it with curl from the host nginx runs at), you can proxy-pass simply observing correct [syntax](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). From the top of my head

```
location /tag { proxy_pass http://expressweb; }
```

Or if you really need regex

```
location ~ /tag/([0-9]+) { prxy_pass http://expressweb/tag/$1; }
```

Here is proxy_pass [syntax](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: again, nginx has nothing to do with page tags, those handled by browser. nginx serves files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I was missing the part of wrapping regex with ().